# JSF-2.2 Faces Flows Return value / cluster / flow return

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I´m currently testing Java EE 7 with JSF 2.2 ( just for fun ). Especially the new Faces Flow looks really great, but I´ve some troubles getting my PoC working.

Questions:
1. If i call a flow from an other, is it possible to check if the current flow is "invoked" by an other one ?

The only solution i found, is to pass a special parameter to the sub flow

2.
 If I call a an other flow via flow-call definition inside the -flow.xml ( for instance a flow where i can select a certain user ). How can i pass a return value to the parent flow ( for instance the selected user )

3.
 Glassfish 4 always complains about, that the flowHandler puts an object into the http sessions, which is not serializable. Is this a bug ? If not does this mean JSF2.2 is not clusterable respectively all open flows will get lost if a cluster node crashes ?

Regards

Comment: To 3. Found this https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2908 I think my glassfish uses an older version of JSF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely clear on your requirements for (1) but FacesFlow does provide the `flowScope` with which You can store pretty much anything you want it's contents are available within the scope of the current flow.

1. Take for example, you've navigated from flow A into flow B. You now want to navigate  from flow B back into flow A *and* also pass parameters back into flow A. What you need to do in your flow definition file for flow A (the parameter **destination flow**), define the parameter you want to pass as **inbound**:

   ```
    <inbound-parameter>
       <name>returnParameterFromB</name>
       <value>#{flowScope.returnParameter}</value>
    </inbound-parameter>
   ```
2. Define the desired parameter as **outbound** in the flow config file of the parameter **source flow** (flow B)

   ```
    <outbound-parameter>
       <name>returnParameterFromB</name>
       <value>#{flowB.returnParameter}</value>
    </outbound-parameter>
   ```
3. While in flow B, you must have stored the necessary value in the `flowScope` object either via EL assignment:

   ```
    <h:inputText value="#{flowB.returnParameter}"/>
   ```

   or in the backing `@FlowScoped` bean:

   ```
    FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<Object, Object> currentFlowScope = ctxt.getApplication().getFlowHandler().getCurrentFlowScope();
    currentFlowScope.put("returnParameter","value");
   ```

Comment: Did not get your example working. The value in the currentFlowScope is not set in the parent flow (A) . I think the value will be set to the child flow (B) which is not available after exiting the flow. Can you provide a full example of the flow A and B ( -flow.xml)

Comment: @urbiwanus If this example does not work why did you mark the answer as the correct solution?

Comment: I used the example above to get an idea. Sorry for marking this as complete correct, but i pointed me in the right direction

Comment: @urbiwanus - what exactly did you do to eventually resolve the issue? You can post a full answer yourself and accept it

Comment: that will be hard since im not working on this project anymore and i dont have access to the source files